# probability of $3$ numbers out of $49$ in a lottery

Tags: probability

If I had to select $10$ numbers out of a possible $49$ in a lottery and no number is to be repeated what is the probability of $3$ numbers coming in the lottery pick.
example - I select $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$ out of numbers $1-49$. What are the chances of numbers $1, 5$ & $7$ being selected in the lottery?

Comment: Does the Lottery Corporation select $10$ numbers?

Comment: is your question this-you choose 10 out of 49 distinct numbers, what's the probability of 3 given numbers(among the 49) to be present among the chosen ten ?

Comment: Looks like a conditional probability question .

Answer (score 1):

You picked $10$ numbers, including $1,5,7$. We will assume that the Lottery Corporation also picks $10$. We ask for the probability the Corporation chooses $1,5,7$ and **none** of your other numbers.

There are $\binom{49}{10}$ ways for the Corporation to pick $10$ numbers. All these choices are assumed equally likely. (And the mechanism the Corporation uses probably more or less ensures that they are.)

The Corporation has to pick $1,5,7$ and $7$ other numbers which do not match your other $7$ numbers. So it must choose $7$ from $39$. This can be done in $\binom{39}{7}$ ways. That gives probability
$$\frac{\binom{39}{7}}{\binom{49}{10}}.$$

But that is probably **not** the probability you are interested in. For gambling purposes, you probably want to find the probability that exactly $3$ of the Corporation's picks match some $3$ of yours. These $3$ can be chosen in $\binom{10}{3}$ ways, so the probability is 
$$\frac{\binom{10}{3}\binom{39}{7}}{\binom{49}{10}}.$$